# What continuity of the derivative has to do with the proof of $\int_a^b f +\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1} =bf(b)-af(a)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-writing

**Question:**

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$  be  **continuously** *differentiable*  and $f'\gt 0$. Prove  that  $$\int_a^bf +\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1} = bf(b)-af(a) $$

**My  problem  with  this :**

$f'\gt 0$  implies  that  $f$  is  strictly  increasing . So  $f$  is  a  function  that  is  continuous  and  strictly  increasing so  injective  also  and  the  inverse  is  also  continuous. Drawing  a picture  of  such a  function  and  considering  *integration*  to  be  the *area  under the curve* I  saw  this above equation  be  true.

In the  previous  chapter  of  this  book  the  same  equation  was  given  to  prove  providing  the informations  $$1) f\ \  is\ \  continuous \\2)f\ \  is\ \  strictly\ \  increasing$$ and I  solved  it  with  the  drawing  method  as  I  mentioned  above .

What  I  do  not  understand  here  is  that  why  the  function  has  to   be  **continuously**  differentiable $?$ Because  only  differentiability and  strict  positivity  of  the  derivative  were together  enough   to  serve  the  purpose , I  think.

Hope  I  have  conveyed  my  thought  properly . Thanks

Comment: You don't *need* that requirement, but assuming it makes the proof easier. The theorem can be proven under weaker assumptions (and one can even relax differentiability if other critera are satisfied). See for example [this Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions). A proof of a more general case can be found [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.3839v4.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

[The right side of your equality should be $bf(b)-af(a)$.] You are correct that this equality holds under the assumption that $f$ is continuous and strictly increasing.  No differentiability is needed, and your "area proof" is doubtless the best way to see this.

The differentiability hypothesis is a mere expedient: It permits your to view the two sides of the identity as functions of $b$, and by differentiating with respect to $b$ (and using the Chain Rule) to see that the two sides can differ only by a constant. That constant is seen to be $0$ by setting $b=a$.

Comment: I  think I  need  to  clarify my question a little more .  When "*continuous and increasing*" is given I did it . And instead when , "*differentiable and $f'\gt 0$*"  is  given  I  find  the  given  conditions to be equivalent . But  the part that looked redundant to me was that  it says  **continuously differentiable** . My problem is  the  **continuously**  part . Why *continuously  differentiable* is required $?$

Comment: Perhaps the poser of the problem had in mind that the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus would be used. In this direction, we could view the right side of the identity as $\int_a^b [xf'(x)+f(x)]\,dx$ provided $xf'(x)+f(x)$ is continuous, whence the need for $f$ to be continuously differentiable.

Comment: Ok . I  think  that  has  been  the  case  .